# Mapping multiple materials to an OBJ model in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I have loaded a model using the DRACO loader and essentially, I get a single model with references to several materials. How could you programmatically match materials to the correct parts of the OBJ?

Please see issue [here on GitHub](https://github.com/google/draco/issues/364#issuecomment-384013287) with a solution needing THREE.js details.